# Database Search minus "The" prefix

Tags: php, mysql, database

could someone please point me in the right direction, I currently have a searchable database and ran into the problem of searching by title.

If the title begins with "The" then obviously the title will be in the 'T' section, what is a good way to avoid "The" being searched ? Should i concat two fields to display the title but search by only the second title ignoring the prefix.  or is there another way to do this?  Advice or direction would be great. thanks.

Comment: what kind of search are you using? A standard LIKE or a Full-Text search?

Comment: So if you had a title like "the taming of the shrew" you would want it to turn up in a search using the term "the" but you would not want "the shining" to turn up?

Comment: ok here's an example, thanks for everyones fast replies;
Paginated results A-Z, you click T and want all things beginning with T, so, "The Shining", would appear under S, am debating this because if people forget or do not know there is a "The" at the start they will not find what they are looking for unless they do a search.   This is for paginated results, A-Z.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few choices:

a) Store the title in "Library" format, which means you process the title and store it as

```
Scarlet Pimpernel, The
Tale of Two Cities, A
```

b) Store the original unchanged title for display purposes, and add a new "library_title" field to store the processed version from a).

c) Add a new field to store the articles, and the bare title in title field. For display, you'd concatenate the two fields, for searching you'd just look in the title field.

Comment: Sorry but the library format has already lost me. Sorry am a newbie

Comment: Would i use an IF statement for those with a 'title' of NULL, and concatonate those with a title ? that simple ?

Comment: Sorted :) thanks, alot easier than i thought, probably haven't done a great job but it is functional :) thanks

Answer (score 2):

I believe the best approach is to use full-text search, with 'the' in the stopwords list. That  would solve the search problem (i.e., 'the' on search phrases would be ignored).

However, if you are ordering the results by title, a title starting with 'The' would still be sorted, "in the 'T' section", as you put it. To solve that, there are several possible approaches. Here are some of them:

- Separating the fields, the way you said on the quesiton
- Having a separate field with the number of chars to be ignored from the beginning when sorting
- Replacing initial 'The's for sorting

Among others...

Comment: any code examples please? I am seriously unqualified in this area, hence the struggle, thanks

Comment: After reading your last comment to the original question, now I believe you don't need full-text search, just a way to order your results. I'd go with one of the options pointed out by @Marc B below.

Answer (score 0):

Create three columns in the database

1) TitlePrefix
2) Title
3) TitlePostfix

Code such that you have 4 methods like

```
searchTitleOnly(testToSearch)  // search only title column
searchTitleWithPrefixAndPostfix(testToSearch)//concat all the three columns and search 
searchTitlePrefix(testToSearch) // search title prefix only
searchTitlePostfix(testToSearch) // search title postfix only
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mysql, you could use a str_replace function to remove "The" from your query, or if you are using PHP or Ruby or another language you can just sanitize your query before sending to the database server.

Comment: There's no need `the` is in the stopword list and will be excluded already.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into some sql functions like LTRIM, RTRIM etc and use these functions on a temp column which has exact same data. Modify the data by using LTRIM, RTRIM by dropping whichever words u please. Then perform the search on the modified column and return the entire row as the result!